# Image tagging software that can sort the tagged images into folders

Tags: images, file-management

I need (preferably gratis) software (for Windows or Linux) to manually tag and sort images, and arrange the images into folders and subfolders.

When it's all said and done, the file structure should look like this (as an example):

```
Event Pics  
│
└───Outside Pics
│   │   img_001.png
│   │   img_002.png
│   │
│   └───Low Light
│       │   img_003.png
│       │   img_004.png
│       │   ...
│   
└───Inside Pics
    │   img_005.png
    │   img_006.png
```

I do not need any special recognition software, I'm tagging these by hand.

Comment: So it would show you a kind of slideshow with buttons to press to add each tag?

Comment: Yes. @NicolasRaoul

Comment: Take a look if [tagspaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) does what you need... It's a file manager where you can tag all files on your computer manually. The Community version is open-source.

Comment: It works, however, tagging things are very slow. Ideally, the tags would be one click to add/remove @Ramuyko